# Firebase Android : pause / resume an UploadTask cause file to not be fully uploaded

Tags: android, firebase, file, uri, firebase-storage

I have a simple `UploadTask` object using Firebase Storage which allows me to upload photos / videos to this storage.

I have added a pause() + resume() logic according to the documentation and it works fine.
I am saving the SessionUri from the `OnProgressListener()`.

When i "play" as testing with the pause() / resume() methods (by clicking on the element in a simple ImageView), i end up sometimes by having the upload succeed and the file has not its full size in the Firebase Storage like this :

[image]

But the upload was successful !
Any ideas to solve this ?

EDIT :

Here is the code to handle the `SessionUri` saving :

```
private void saveUriSession(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot, Post post) {
        if (taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri() != null && !isSessionUriRegistered(post.getPostID())) {
            Log.d(TAG, "saveUriSession: saving session.");
            saveSharedPreference.setUriSession(taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri().toString(), post);
        }
    }

    public Boolean isSessionUriRegistered(String uid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "isSessionUriRegistered: " + saveSharedPreference.getUriSession(uid));
        return !saveSharedPreference.getUriSession(uid).toString().equals("");
    }
```

And this is the code called to resume / pause the upload :

```
// Current upload task
private UploadTask uploadTask;

private UploadTask uploadImage(Post post) {
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadImage: compressing image...");
        byte[] bytes = imageManagerBitmap.getBytesFromBitmap(post.getFile(), 100);
        uploadTask = firebaseAPI.updatePostImage(post.getPostID(), bytes);
        return uploadTask;
    }

public void uploadFileToDB(Post post) {
  uploadImage(post).addOnProgressListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                    // If the session is not already saved we save it
                    saveUriSession(taskSnapshot, post);
                    if (taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount() != 0) {
                        long progressCount = 100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                        //progressBytes.setValue(progressCount);
                    }
                });
}

public Boolean pauseUpload() {
        if (uploadTask != null) {
            return uploadTask.pause();
        }
        return false;
    }

public Boolean resumeUpload() {
        if (uploadTask != null) {
            return uploadTask.resume();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The `resumeUpload()` and the `pauseUpload()` methods are called on the `ImageView` `onClickListener()` method with a boolean that handles the switch.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: The code is just fine, i just suspect Firebase to terminate the upload session because of a wrong amount of ```bytes``` when the ```resume()``` method is called. The ```SessionUri``` is used only when the user destroys the application and restart it, there is no problem with this.